# Why does it take so long for ng-click to work again?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

EDIT:
ng-dbclick does not work for me or it would be used here.

### Original:

I have a button. I click it once, it works as expected. I click it again, it does not work. I wait maybe a minute more, and then it does work. My function associated with the button does have lots of returns and if loops which call other functions, but the thing is, it does work perfectly each time it does. Here, I have implemented a double click function (hence the counter is 1 and 2, and it does work) - the project is marked as complete when double clicked, otherwise on a single click it is paused or started depending on its status.

I know I probably don't understand the digest or eval cycles here, or may need to use $scope.apply()...I basically don't understand those concepts at all or where to use them. I do have $http get and post requests in my nested functions.

Code from the HTML file:

```
<button ng-click="resumeorpauseproject(project, project.id)">Click me</button>
```

Code from the controller file:

```
$scope.resumeorpausecounter = 0;

$scope.resumeorpauseproject = function(value1, value2){


        $scope.resumeorpausecounter = $scope.resumeorpausecounter + 1;


        $timeout(function () {
            if ($scope.resumeorpausecounter == 1) {


                $scope.resumeorpauseproject1(value1, value2);
                return;

            }

            if ($scope.resumeorpausecounter == 2) {

                /*$scope.resumeorpausecounter = false;*/


                $scope.markprojectascomplete(value1, value2);
                return;

            }


        }, 300);


};
```

Comment: Create a plunkr with the code allowing us to reproduce the problem. Define precisely what you expect the function to do, and what it does when it "doesn't work".

Comment: no way for us to know what the functions you call are doing. Show all relevant code in a clean format

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/FNrP5Q9ivQR55zuLTa6U?p=preview

What you are trying to do is crazy imo.

Just model it properly and use ng-dblclick. You don't actually need to apply $digest nor $apply if understand your case correctly.

If we **just think in terms of functionality**, what you have is a project, and it **should be marked as completed when doubleclicked**, and should **be toggled between started and stopped on single click**:
Here is the relevant js:

```
 project.state = {
     started: false,
     completed: false,
     toggleStarted: function toggleStarted(){
       this.started = !this.started;
     },
     markCompleted: function markCompleted(){
       this.completed = true;
     }
 };
```

And here is the relevant html:

```
<button 
    data-ng-click="project.state.toggleStarted()"
    data-ng-dblclick="project.state.markCompleted()"
>
    Click me
</button>
```

Comment: ng-dblclick does not work at all for me. I did try it before.

Comment: It is not "crazy". There are a lot of things that won't work inside one big function in my experience with AngularJS code, so breaking it up into lots of little nested functions was a lot easier. I am trying to learn new and better approaches though.

Comment: Why doesn't ng-dbclick work for you? What do you want to achieve? You want, when dbl-clicked, to mark your project as completed, and on single click, you want to toggle the started state, right? In software engineering, it's almost never OK to reinvent the wheel, so I'd suggest to phrase your requirements clearly and see if there are existing things out there that help you do what you want to do (in this case ng-dblclick)